# Howto create multiple batch files from large csv file based on conditional sum of a column using python

Tags: python, list, csv, sum

I have a csv file containing two columns.
col 1 = filepaths
col 2 = file size

It is a large list with thousands of rows.

the aim is to use that list to copy the files in col 1 to several external 2 TB USB disks for archiving.

I wanted to split the csv file into multiple smaller files containing list of files that can fit within the formatted capacity of one of the hard drives.
that way, the operators can perform the copy operation in batches, which is more manageable.

I need to obtain the "rows_per_csv" value based on the sum of col 2 upto the hard drive size threshold.
so for a 2 TB HDD that's about 1.8TB.

I am having a bit of difficulty with my loop. It's returning one page, but I can't seem to get it to continue to get the other pages
after the first threshold is hit whilst summing the column.

can you please help me figure out what I'm missing?
I want to use basic builtin python functions, not pandas, as I'm still slowly learning python.
I did get inspiration from this post https://gist.github.com/kelvintaywl/37dbfaea789707ec5f48 and was trying to modify it for my purpose.

your assistance is appreciated.

UPDATE: I had another go at it. Added the while loop in the for statement. That seems to have made some difference. it's working now, but the if statement may need reviewing, probably use a percentage of the HDD size instead. because the >= is causing the batch files to be bigger than the formatted capacity.

UPDATE (10/08/2020): I've made some progress and worked out a system that seems to work fine. I used a low threshold and a high threshold to ensure I get enough rows that will fit the HDD. Effective a range in the if statement. The lower threshold is a percentage figure of the formatted capacity of the HDD. the higher threshold is the formatted capacity of the HDD. So basically, the statement required to create the pages would read like "if sum of of the rows is greater than the lower threshold but lower or equal to the higher threshold" [if lower_threshold  < sum_of_rows <= int(hdd_size_bytes)], create a page. That appears to be working fine. just need to adjust the percentile used to get the optimal number of rows in a page. Also create a small function "pct_of_num" to calculate the percentage deduction figure.

below is sample of what I have so far.

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
main_csvfile_path = pathlib.Path(script_path) / 'CSV Files/main_filelist_test.csv'
batchfiles_dirpath = pathlib.Path(script_path) / 'Batch Files'
hdd_size_bytes = 1979120929997 # 1.8TB formatted capacity
pct_deduction = 98 # Percentage deduction from hdd_size_bytes. Ok for 1.8 TB HDD

def pct_of_num(pct, num):
    # Description: Get lower threshold figure from percentage deduction of the formatted capacity of the HDD.
    # Required Modules: None
    pct_figure = num * pct/100
    return pct_figure

def create_batches(filepath):
    batch_filename = pathlib.Path(batchfiles_dirpath) / 'batchfile'
    lower_threshold = pct_of_num(pct_deduction, hdd_size_bytes)
    print(f"Reading source file {filepath}")
    with open(filepath, newline='') as main_csvfile:
        try:
            rows = [row for row in csv.reader(main_csvfile)]
            batches = []

            row_count = len(rows)
            start_index = 0
            rows_per_csv = 0
            sum_of_rows = 0

            print(f"Row Count: {row_count}")

            for row in rows:
              while start_index < row_count:

                 row_of_size = int(row[1])
                 sum_of_rows += row_of_size
                 rows_per_csv += 1

                 print(f"Batch {len(batches)}, Row {start_index + rows_per_csv} : {row}")
                 if lower_threshold < sum_of_rows <= int(hdd_size_bytes):
                     print(f"Sum of rows is {sum_of_rows}")
                     print(f"Row Per csv: {rows_per_csv}")
                     batches.append(rows[start_index: start_index + rows_per_csv])
                     start_index += rows_per_csv
                     sum_of_rows = 0
                     rows_per_csv = 0
                 break
       batches.append(rows[start_index: start_index + rows_per_csv])
       print(f"Sum of rows is {sum_of_rows}")
       print(f"Row Per csv: {rows_per_csv}")
       print(f"Total Batches: {len(batches)}")

       print(f"Writing new batch files in {filepath}")
            for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
               with open('{}_{}.csv'.format(batch_filename, i+1), 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
                    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                    for row in batch:
                        writer.writerow(row)
        except Exception:
            print(f"An error occured whilst reading the file '{filepath.name}'", exc_info=True)
            sys.exit()

# Main Script
def main():
    # Create batch files from main csv file
    create_batches(main_csvfile_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You might consider sorting the files by size and writing the biggest ones to disk first so that the files are more likely to fit on fewer disks.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is a good idea. However, I came up with a  solution described in my last update, that appears to have done what I wanted.